# How to partiotion a disk for Debian install such as user files are independant from OS and BTRFS snapshot feature is enabled?

Tags: partition, disk, btrfs, debian-installer, bios

## Hi everyone,

### This is my first time installing Debian, and I'm trying to achieve that in legacy BIOS mode, but I'm having a bit of trouble finding the best way of partitioning my disk.

One way I found that I think would be good is to create 3 partitions: Boot, Root & Home;
that way if the system or bootloader ever break, I could just reinstall it without losing my files and system settings. **However** I would also like to use BTRFS, and in the tutorials showing how to implement it, only one Root partition is created and then a "home" subvolume under it.

---

I would like to know how I should partition my disk so that I can:

1. reinstall the OS or botloader without losing my files and settings in case of a crash.
2. benefit from the BTRFS snapshot feature.

---

*PS: I'm also planning to add a SWAP partition but I don't think it's relevant to my problem.*

**Thanks in advance :)**

Comment: While installing, use "Separate /home partition". Check the [official installation guide](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch06s03.en.html#partman-auto) (this one is for amd64).

Comment: @EduardoTrápani thank you for your answer, but that's not really what I was looking for, as I also want to be able to use BTRFS snapshot feature on all partitions. Do you have any suggestions for that?